# Apache Jena cannot update RDF triple store using jsonld file

Tags: jena

I'am using the tdb2.tdbloader (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb2/tdb2_cmds.html) to update an existing graph with a jsonld file, but this fails with a warning. Note it works with the equivalent mydata.rdf file, but I don't really want to convert jsonld to RDF.

How can I update my graph using jsonld format files?

```
apache-jena-4.10.0/bin/tdb2.tdbloader -loc database/ -v -graph http://g1 mydata.jsonld
Warning: Quads format given - only the default graph is loaded into the graph for --graph
```

I was expecting the tdb2.tdbloader to be able to update the graph using mydata.jsonld - which is valid jsonld.

Comment: jsonld can contain more than one graph so its like TriG or N-Quads. The loader does not know if it is a single graph or not when it starts.
You can convert it with the riot command. TDB2 does not store RDF by syntax, it stores triples and quads so converting makes little difference. try `riot mydata.jsonld | tdb2.tdbloader -loc DB2 -graph http://g1`

Comment: Cheers AndyS, that worked !

Comment: I've turned it into an answer to make it more findable if you coudl accept that.
Also - I put in a PR to Jena for a change to be less careful about loading JSON-LD files into the default graph.
The solution above is still better for loading a named graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsonld can contain more than one graph - it is like TriG or N-Quads. The loader does not know if it is a single graph or not when it starts. You can convert it with the riot command. TDB2 does not store RDF by syntax, it stores triples and quads so converting makes little difference.

```
riot mydata.jsonld | tdb2.tdbloader -loc DB2 -graph http://g1
```